# I need to place 4 background pictures, then when hovering the images will change its postion

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to make a page where I've got 4 background pictures one behind another, and when I hover the mouse over them, the first picture goes to top left, the second to bottom left, the third, top right and the last one bottom right.

I've managed to work this out with the first one, it is exactly what I need to, but the other pictures do not even appear behind the first one, when I hover the mouse, it is just blank space. I'm using CSS because it is all I know at the moment, I have some notions of javascript but I do not know if it can help me with this issue. I put the code here for better understanding.

In the end, I just need to repeat this code 4 times, just changing the position, but I can't make it work as simple as I thought.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("i3.jpg"), url("i4.jpg"), url("class.jpg"), url("prod.jpg");
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center, center, center, center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-size: cover, cover, cover, cover;
}

.bg {
  /* Isso aqui deixa a imagem em preto e branco */
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: gray;
  /* IE 6-9 */
  transition: filter .5s ease-in-out;
}

.bg:hover {
  /* Isso aqui ativa o hover */
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}

.bg {
  /* Isso aqui é do hover 1 */
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.bg:hover {
  /* Isso aqui é do hover 2 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to change the `background-position` of all the images on hover...

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/80x80"), url("http://via.placeholder.com/80x80"), url("http://via.placeholder.com/80x80"), url("http://via.placeholder.com/80x80");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.bg:hover {
  background-position: top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, thank you. But I was thinking in moving each image as I hover the mouse over it at a time. I mean, like layers:
hover-> Top left; hover again-> Bottom left: hover again -> Top right; hover again-> Bottom right. I keep getting the images below one another, not behind and this is a big issue now.

Comment: Actually, maybe this is way beyond my skills hahaha, but if I may, how can I make the code you posted here work for full background pictures? I mean, I have 4 pictures that I want to build this "mosaic" with, but when I apply the code it kinda zooms in the "top left" position, for example, when what I needed was shrinking the images to that position. I maed it work with one picture, but not with four haha.

Comment: @VictorRhéa sorry to say, but its not clear what you are asking here...?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe it is hard to me explain it. But let met try one more time; In the code you brought here the images are 80x80, right? And they are one behind another before the hover, exactly as I want to do. But my images are full background pictures, and I'm not able to stack them as in your example. This is my problem at this moment.

Comment: @VictorRhéa you can set the background size using `background-size` css...

Answer (score 0):

I would break up the images into four separate images (with different class names) and use the z-index property.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried to use the z-index property, but the images do not get "stacked" behind the previous one, they keep getting below, extending the page length.